# Update Query will not run

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

When I run the query (1st Code) below I get 1.37 million random Departure Dates based on the current Arrival Date in the database, this is good news. However when I try to update the database with the 2nd Code query I get an error message(See below) and I don't know why. Can you help?

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

**1st Code**

```
SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate) AS DepartureDate    
FROM Bookings, LengthOfStay
ORDER BY ArrivalDate
```

**2nd Code**

```
USE Occupancy
Update Bookings
Set DepartureDate = (SELECT ArrivalDate, DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5
* LengthOfStay.LengthofStay, ArrivalDate))
FROM LengthOfStay, Bookings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

- `LengthOfStay, Bookings` is a CROSS JOIN (Cartesian product): is this intended
- You have 2 columns from the sub query but are trying to update only one

Assuming your CROSS JOIN is intended, you don't need the subquery

```
UPDATE
   B
SET
   DepartureDate = DATEADD(day,
                           1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5 * L.LengthofStay,
                          B.ArrivalDate)
FROM
   LengthOfStay L, Bookings B
```

Comment: Hi gbn, Does the above update query still randomise my length of stay?

Comment: Hello again gbn, it seems the randomising has changed, before on my select query I would get the departure randomising between 1 and 28 days the query below has only used 1 and 2 days.

USE Occupancy
Update B
Set DepartureDate = DATEADD(day, 1 + RAND(checksum(NEWID()))*1.5 * L.LengthofStay, B.ArrivalDate)
FROM LengthOfStay L, Bookings B

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are selecting 2 columns to update 1 column(DepartureDate)